# Custom scikit-learn scorer can't access mean after fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a custom estimator based on scikit learn. I have written the below dummy code to explain my problem. In the score method, I am trying to access `mean_` calulated in fit. But I am unable to. What I am doing wrong? I have tried many things and have done this referring three four articles. But didn't find the issue.

I have read the documentation and did few changes. But nothing worked. I have also tried inheriting `BaseEstimator`, `ClassifierMixin`. But that also didn't work.

This a dummy program. Don't go by what it is trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


class FilterElems:
    def __init__(self, thres):
        self.thres = thres

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X)
        self.std_ = np.std(X)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        #         return sign(self.predict(inputs))
        X = (X - self.mean_) / self.std_
        return X[X > self.thres]

    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'thres': self.thres}

    def score(self, *x):
        print(self.mean_)  # errors out, mean_ and std_ are wiped out
        if len(x[1]) > 50:
            return 1.0
        else:
            return 0.5


model = FilterElems(thres=0.5)
print(cross_val_score(model,
                      np.random.randint(1, 1000, (100, 100)),
                      None,
                      scoring=model.score,
                      cv=5))
```

Err:

> AttributeError: 'FilterElems' object has no attribute 'mean_'

Comment: Hi ggaurav, are you still looking for an answer for this? If so, I can add a bounty, which makes it more likely you'll get an answer by offering extra points for an accepted answer. The bounty costs me my own stack overflow reputation though, so if you've figured out a solution on your own since then I'd ask you to post your own solution instead. Just let me know here. I think this was a good question and I was surprised no one answered so far, although the solution is definitely nonobvious.

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for an answer. For my problem, I did a workaround and did a custom loop to do cross validation for my NLP task. I would have added bounty myself, but it is quite less, so am saving for any further question I d have. Thanks!

Comment: You have fitted the model right? Although it does not appear in the code

Comment: cross_val_score does the cross validation where fit would be automatically called; 5 times in this case as this is 5-fold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.

The signature for scorer is `scorer(estimator, X, y)`. The `cross_val_score` calls the `scorer` method by passing the `estimator` object as the first parameter. Since your signature of `scorer` is a variable argument function, the first item will hold the `estimator`

change your score to

```
def score(self, *x):
    print(x[0].mean_)
    if len(x[1]) > 50:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 0.5
```

**Working code**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

class FilterElems:
    def __init__(self, thres):
        self.thres = thres

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X)
        self.std_ = np.std(X)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        X = (X - self.mean_) / self.std_
        return X[X > self.thres]

    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'thres': self.thres}

    def score(self, estimator, *x):
        print(estimator.mean_, estimator.std_) 
        if len(x[0]) > 50:
            return 1.0
        else:
            return 0.5

model = FilterElems(thres=0.5)
print(cross_val_score(model,
                      np.random.randint(1, 1000, (100, 100)),
                      None,
                      scoring=model.score,
                      cv=5))
```

Outout

```
504.750125 288.84916035447355
501.7295 289.47825925231416
503.743375 288.8964170227962
503.0325 287.8292687406025
500.041 289.3488678377712
[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
```

Comment: I was in notion that  "self" would take estimator object. Can you elaborate on how this scenario is different from a normal object scenario?

Comment: @ggaurav `cross_val_score` points to the `score` method of the `model` object. `cross_val_score` internally creates new copies of `FilterElems` class and trains (`fit`) them on the different folds. When it has to score the models it will call the `score` method of `model` by passing these models in `estimator` or `x[0]` in your case. So `self` points to `model` object and `x[0]` point the object on which the `fit` is run. `fit` is not run on `model` but on the copies so `self` which points to `model` will not have `mean`.

Comment: @ggaurav  All this confusion is because you made `score` a class method, think what will happen if it is not a class method but a normal method ?

Comment: got that; I called fit and score seperately and it worked with my code also. Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason for having `score` inside `FilterElems` because you are not using `self` in that method. Thats why the recommend way is to have an independent method.

Comment: thanks for the explanations @mujiga. Can I ask, given that you said " All this confusion is because you made score a class method, think what will happen if it is not a class method but a normal method"...can I ask why you added this answer instead of supporting  Venkatachalam's? It sounds like you agree his answer is the recommended one?

Answer (score 2):

The input for `scoring` param in `cross_val_score` needs to `str` or `callable` with signature `scoring(estimator, X, y)`. In your case, you don't seems to need the `y`, hence you can leave that in your callable. Also, you need to ensure that the output of the score has to be single value.

The solution would look something like this for your problem.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class FilterElems(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, thres):
        self.thres = thres

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X)
        self.std_ = np.std(X)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        #         return sign(self.predict(inputs))
        X = (X - self.mean_) / self.std_
        return X[X > self.thres]

    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'thres': self.thres}


def scorer(tranformer, X):
    print(tranformer.mean_)  # Now it prints out, mean_ and std_ 
    result=[]
    for x in X:
        # do the stuff you want here
        if x[1] > 50:
            result.append(1)
        else:
            result.append(0.5)
    # but return a single value
    return np.mean(result)

np.random.seed(1)
model = FilterElems(thres=0.5)
print(cross_val_score(model,
                      np.random.randint(1, 1000, (100, 100)),
                      None,
                      scoring=scorer,
                      cv=5))

# [0.95  1.    1.    0.975 0.975]
```

Comment: Now, the scorer doesn't belong to FilterElems. How can we use it as a part of the class. Also, predict method is still not a working one as mean_ is not accessible there. In most of the cases, I would also need to use predict method. Currently, this answer looks like a workaround..

Comment: We cannot use the methods which are part of the class because `cross_val_score` clones the given class for every combination of n folds, hence there is no state for the provided class method in scorer. Please let me know what error you got in predict methods.

Comment: Hi ggaurav, I was able to run this solution where the predict method does indeed have access to mean_. Are you sure this answer doesn't meet your requirements? If not, can you elaborate on why it is a requirement that scorer function be a class method of FilterElem? It seems like both answerers agree that in sklearn a scorer function should not be particular to a transform/model class, and that design philosophy makes a lot of sense to me.